# interfacing markup/git with Word for document collaboration

Tags: linux, document-management, document-converter, version-control, microsoft-word

## summary

partner A: underling, coder, Linux and FLOSS user, lives in text editor and web browser, accustomed to collaborating using `git` repos (local and online) and online-repo-supported markup.

partner B: boss, scientist, Mac user of Microsoft Office, accustomed to collaborating using Word version control.

How to enable partners to collaborate on some relatively short, simple documents with minimal stress to !Microsoft-user A and !power-user B?

## details

### partners

Partners (of which B is definitely the senior) need to collaborate on some short, simple documents. These documents

- will not be longer than a few pages
- will not contain (e.g.) figures/images, equations, or other serious DTP functionality.
- should be web-publishable but will also need to be printed for some meetings.

Partner A (P<sub>a</sub>) knows from experience that "this sort of thing" is easily accomplished with markup dialect (e.g., Markdown, MediaWiki, reStructuredText) and soft-document converters (e.g., `pandoc`). For collaboration, P<sub>a</sub> would vastly prefer to manage/version the documents as markup within local and online `git` repos.

Partner B (P<sub>b</sub>) is the boss; notably, P<sub>b</sub> has "final cut" on the documents. P<sub>b</sub> has never used any repository or any markup, even for a wiki. P<sub>b</sub> mostly lives on Mac except for occasional Windows forays for ArcGIS, and uses mostly Microsoft tools (including Office and Outlook). P<sub>b</sub> considers open-source and open-science "shiny objects" that are "politically correct," whereas Word version control is State of the Art for document collaboration. P<sub>a</sub> currently lacks access to Microsoft tools, and anyway finds they make him vomit--esp Word "version control."

### candidate usecase

P<sub>a</sub> would vastly prefer a document-collaboration process that would allow "roundtripping" git+markup ↔ Word. P<sub>a</sub> prefers [reStructuredText](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReStructuredText), but would be happy to use any markup supported by any of the major online `git` repos (e.g., Bitbucket, GitHub) and by a reasonably-competent web- or Linux-available markup converter (e.g., `pandoc`). P<sub>a</sub> envisions a usecase like the following loop:

1. P<sub>a</sub> authors markup, commits to repo
2. P<sub>a</sub> generates `.docx` from markup
3. P<sub>a</sub> forwards `.docx` via email attachment
4. P<sub>b</sub> is happy `?` exit `:` edits `.docx` in Word and returns
5. P<sub>a</sub> generates markup from `.docx`. [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) (only) can be generated from `.docx` with Ben Balter's [ruby gem](https://github.com/benbalter/word-to-markdown) or its related [website](http://word-to-markdown.herokuapp.com/).
6. P<sub>a</sub> `diff`s current/P<sub>b</sub> markup against previous/committed markup
7. P<sub>a</sub> commits current/P<sub>b</sub> markup with comment derived from previous step (and anything else P<sub>b</sub> may have said in email)
8. P<sub>a</sub> edits markup, commits to repo
9. loop to step#=2

Note that

P<sub>a</sub> is unfortunately unaware of a tool that can accomplish step#=5. E.g.,

### questions

In order of increasing importance:

1. Is there a tool that can convert reST → Word? In the above pipeline, the Balter tools are (IIUC) restricted to Markdown. Furthermore, in my admittedly quite-limited testing, the website's conversion was a bit wonky (esp with list items, IIRC). That being said, I am aware of literally no other tool that does this conversion. Notably, `pandoc` can *write* `.docx` and ODT (i.e., step#=2) but cannot *read* them. (Am I missing something?)
2. Is there another way (`Something Completely Different`) to accomplish the P<sub>a</sub>'s goals other than the candidate usecase? Which is obviously more than a little cumbersome.

Comment: Not sure if tools for such a workflow exist which would satisfy A and B; but maybe consider two alternative approaches: 1) Give B a WYSIWYG markdown editor looking very similar to what he's used to, and take a WebDAV storage with versioning to save documents to, 2) Use e.g. *ownCloud*, which includes such an editor and does versioning in the background (documents are available then via WebDAV and the browser, can even be sync'd).

Comment: @Izzy: alas, P_b is very Word-centric. It is the Way, the Truth, and the Light(tm).

Comment: locked-in to the dark side, huh? OK, chances go asymptotic to the x-axis then I'm afraid :( Unless he *uses* his favorite toy, but saves into RTF format – which should go easy with versioning tools (being non-binary except for "embedded image blobs" if any), and also be understood by Pandoc IIRC. But then, much formatting might be lost.